# Unlabeled Headers/Pins on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, hardware, pins

Looking at my Arduino Uno, I noticed that not all of the pins/headers are labelled.  I know what most of the pins do, but could not figure some of them (most not labelled at all, and one set labelled ICSP, but I don't know what that means).

So, my question is: What purpose do these pins (circled in red) serve?

[image: Arduino Board with circled pins]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ICSP pins are for programming the Arduino directly with an ISP/ICSP programmer. This lets you do things like mess with the bootloader/etc. Basically, while the Arduino bootloader understands UART (the Rx/Tx business), the AVR microcontroller doesn't, so if you want to program it directly, you have to use the ICSP pins.

See [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Programmer) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67080/how-should-one-switch-from-using-an-arduino-as-a-programmer-to-an-external-progr) for more details.

[image]

The set of 6 pins near the AREF pin are the ICSP for the USB system.  The USB interface has its own microcontroller (AFAICT it is the [ATmega16u2](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega16u2.aspx) in the Uno Rev 3). Apparently folks use this to make it keyboard- or mouse-compatible.

Regarding that lone pin -- it's disconnected. Looking at the [schematic](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf), one can see that IOREF is nothing but a +5V voltage reference pin, and that pin 1 (the unknown pin) is disconnected.

[image]

Comment: There are **lots** of reasons to tweak the ATmega16U2. Having it enumerate as a keyboard/mouse/midi-device/whatever rather then a serial port is one common one.

Comment: @ConnorWolf: hm, that does make sense :)